# Installing Tkinter on Qpython

Tags: android, python, tkinter, qpython

I see that Tkinter for qpython is available ( https://github.com/qpython-android/qpython3-core/blob/master/python3-src/Doc/library/tkinter.rst )  but it is not installed by default with Qpython app on android.

How can I install Tkinter on Qpython on android device? I could not get the answer from website. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QPython or QPython3 do not support tkiner yet.

Maybe you can give a try kivy on QPython as the GUI solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a try by downloading termux than u can try using:
$ LDFLAGS=" -lm -lcompiler_rt" pip tkinter